# What is the difference of using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What is the main difference between of using this:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    // code
}, false);
```

...and this?

```
document.onmousedown = function() {
    // code
}
```

Will there be any different result or any cause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onclick` is a property, like the `onclick` attribute can be placed in HTML. It has best browser support, however, it is primitive, as reassigning it overwrites the first (like any object property).

`addEventListener()`, as the name suggests, allows you to register multiple callbacks for an element and event type. This allows you to have multiple `mousedown` events for the same element. Before IE9, IE had their own `attachEvent()` which is similar (you must specify the `on` part too with `attachEvent()`).